How to INSERT 6 VALUES simultaneously in column named salary in Table named employees TABLE has 6 employee ids in emp_id column
I have these values(mentioned BELOW) which i'm trying to insert in (newly made) salary column of employees table. Salary column is INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 25000.
37000, 32000, 35000, 45000, 55000, 37000.
I have got these values for emp_id column which are already there
101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106
I've tried these syntax
INSERT INTO employees(Salary)
 VALUES (37000), (32000), (35000), (45000), (55000), (37000);

and
ALTER table employees INSERT INTO Salary VALUES (37000, 32000, 35000, 45000, 55000, 37000);

and many more but won't embarrass myself more xD
[]

ALTER TABLE is for modifying the table schema, not the contents. You're thinking of UPDATE.

INSERT creates new rows, it doesn't add to existing rows.

You can use UPDATE to modify the Salary column of existing rows. But how do you determine which value goes in which row?

Use UPDATE to modify the contents of existing rows. Use CASE to specify the value for each employee ID.
UPDATE employees
SET Salary = CASE emp_id
    WHEN 101 THEN 37000
    WHEN 102 THEN 32000
    WHEN 103 THEN 35000
    -- and so on for all employee IDs
    ELSE Salary -- leave unchanged if not in the above list
END


Worked! Well, experts are experts.

Use UPDATE. Provide the id-salary values pairs as a datasource:
UPDATE employees
JOIN ( SELECT 101, 37000 UNION ALL
       SELECT 102, 32000 UNION ALL
       SELECT 103, 35000 UNION ALL
       SELECT 104, 45000 UNION ALL
       SELECT 105, 55000 UNION ALL
       SELECT 106, 37000) AS new_salary (emp_id, salary) USING (emp_id)
SET employees.salary = new_salary.salary;


This worked too! Your guidance is appreciated.
